# I just picture appears with BLOB Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
Header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$DBhost = "localhost";
$DBuser = "root";
$DBpass = "";
$DBName = "cinema";
$table = "film";
mysql_connect($DBhost,$DBuser,$DBpass) or die("Impossibile collegarsi al server");
@mysql_select_db("$DBName") or die("Impossibile connettersi al database $DBName");
$sql = "SELECT copertina FROM film";
$result = @mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error ());
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row[0];
}
$DBhost = "localhost";
$DBuser = "root";
$DBpass = "";
$DBName = "cinema";
$table = "filmorario";
mysql_connect($DBhost,$DBuser,$DBpass) or die("Impossibile collegarsi al server");
@mysql_select_db("$DBName") or die("Impossibile connettersi al database $DBName");
$sqltwo = "SELECT id_orario FROM filmorario WHERE id_film=1";
$resulttwo = @mysql_query($sqltwo) or die (mysql_error ());
while ($rowtwo = @mysql_fetch_array($resulttwo))
{
echo $rowtwo[0];
}
```

Why appears only one query at a time, if I remove the first appears the second and if I remove the second appears the first.

This is the database of "film":

[image]

And this is the database of filmorario:

[image]

I must insert id_orario next to the image.

Comment: You don't need to connect DB again in same file and also use mysql_close() for closing of connection.

Answer (score 0):

Change `echo $row[0];` to `echo $row["copertina"];`. Then try it again you will find all results.

Comment: Thank you Sathvik for the answer but i have the same problem after the change. I don't know if this is important but the second query is a text , only the first is an image can be this the problem?

Comment: Can you update you question with the screenshot of front end and database table . So that I can understand it more clear.

Comment: And try to change `echo $rowtwo[0];` to `echo $rowtwo["id_orario"];`

Comment: I have insert the images of two table thank you for the help.